# XSL - FO wrong output character in pdf

Tags: xslt, encoding, oracle-apex, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I use xsl fo as oracle apex report layout. After generate .pdf document some character is not correctly. Here is a lot of question and answer about that but nothing helped me.

In my solution I have this character:

```
<fo:block font-family="Tahoma">ČĆŽŠĐ  čćžšđ</fo:block>
```

In pdf document get `##ŽŠ# ##žš#`

I'm try different solution (change font, use encoding-mode="single-byte"...)

Is it possible put font path from online website?

Any solution?

Comment: The FOP docs say: "Every font contains a particular set of glyphs. If no glyph can be found for a given character, FOP will issue a warning and use the glpyh for "#" (if available) instead.". Does Tahoma support those characters rendered as '#'? Which FOP version do you use?

Comment: @MartinHonnen  Tahoma  support those characters, I don't know how and where 
 view FOP version?

Comment: Do you know the Java JRE version you use? Also, if you use XSL-FO, I don't think you want the tag `xls` for Excel, if you want help fo XSL-FO then add the right tag for that `xsl-fo`. I have tried your sample with Java 8 without any particular setup for FOP and the same characters are displayed as '#'. However, when I used oXygen XML editor (which runs on Java 11 and probably has a specialized setup for good FOP support), the characters are rendered fine as `ČĆŽŠĐ čćžšđ ', I can't tell whether that is the font you want or some replacement that FOP under oXygen uses.

Comment: I have now tried FOP 2.4 with Java 8 and it directly tells me 'Font "Tahoma,normal,400" not found. Substituting with "any,normal,400"' and then outputs warnings for all those missing characters e.g. 'Glyph "?" (0x10c, Ccaron) not available in font "Times-Roman".'. I will see whether Java 11 gives a better result.

Comment: The difference doesn't seem to be the Java version but that oXygen runs FOP with a `.xconf` file that has the setting `<auto-detect/>` in the section for fonts and that way it seems FOP "will look for other fonts in the fonts installed in the operating system". From the command line you can run FOP with `-c configuration-file.xconf`, I am afraid I can't help with the necessary oracle-apex setup/configuration.